# systemd-tmpfiles race condition

Tags: linux, centos, centos7, systemd

I have a config file `/etc/tmpfiles.d/test.conf`:

```
z /dir/*         660 -    -    -
z /dir/subdir   2770 -    -    -
z /dir/subdir/*  660 -    -    -
Z /dir             - root test -
```

When I run `systemd-tmpfiles --prefix=/dir --create /etc/tmpfiles.d/test.conf ; ll /dir`, access rights of `/dir/subdir` are randomly

- sometimes `drwxrws---` (from the `/dir/*` rule) and
- sometimes `drw-rw----` (from the `/dir/subdir` rule).

How do I make it deterministic?

The point is that directory `/dir` contains a lot of files and one subdirectory and I want to set `rw` access rights to the files and `rwx` access rights to the subdirectory.

Centos 7

[man tmpfiles.d](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/tmpfiles.d.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Literal (un)match of `/dir/subdir` in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/test.conf`:

```
z /dir/[!s]*       660 -    -    -
z /dir/s[!u]*      660 -    -    -
z /dir/su[!b]*     660 -    -    -
z /dir/sub[!d]*    660 -    -    -
z /dir/subd[!i]*   660 -    -    -
z /dir/subdi[!r]*  660 -    -    -
z /dir/subdir?*    660 -    -    -
z /dir/subdir     2770 -    -    -
z /dir/subdir/*    660 -    -    -
Z /dir               - root test -
```

Suffix (un)match of `/dir/*.test.sh` in `/etc/tmpfiles.d/test.conf`:

```
z /dir/*[!t].sh     750 - - -
z /dir/*[!s]t.sh    750 - - -
z /dir/*[!e]st.sh   750 - - -
z /dir/*[!t]est.sh  750 - - -
z /dir/*[!.]test.sh 750 - - -
z /dir/*.test.sh    500 - - -
```

I don't like this solution. Someone please come up with anything better.